# How to speed up a slow update query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update query that works fine, but it is way too slow and takes over 2 minutes to complete.  Is there another way I can write this query to speed it up? Here is my code thanks:

```
UPDATE #tmpIMDS 
SET 
    ModelFileName = b.ModelFileName,    
    SendEMail = b.SendEMail 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        IMDSConversionReportData.ModelNumber,
        ModelFileName,
        'Send Email' AS SendEmail       
    FROM 
        IMDSConversionReportData,           
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                ModelNumber,
                Max(DateAdded) AS DateAdded             
            FROM 
                IMDSConversionReportData            
            GROUP BY 
                ModelNumber) a      
            WHERE 
                IMDSConversionReportData.ModelNumber = a.ModelNumber
                AND IMDSConversionReportData.DateAdded = a.DateAdded 
        ) b
        WHERE ModelID = b.ModelNumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hitting `IMDSConversionReportData` table twice to get the maximum `DateAdded` per `ModelNumber` you can generate `row_number` to identify maximum `DateAdded` per `ModelNumber`column.

Also remove `distinct` when you are selecting only one non aggregate column with `group by` which is meaningless

Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                'Send Email'  AS SendEmail,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY ModelNumber ORDER BY DateAdded DESC) AS rn
         FROM   IMDSConversionReportData)
UPDATE t
SET    ModelFileName = c.ModelFileName,
       SendEMail = c.SendEMail
FROM   #tmpIMDS t
       INNER JOIN cte c
               ON t.ModelID = c.ModelNumber 
Where Rn = 1
```

**Note :** Always use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax to join two tables instead of Old style comma separated join. We always find `INNER Join` syntax is more **readable**. Keep the filters alone in `Where` clause

Comment: The multi-part identifier "b.ModelFileName" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "b.SendEMail" could not be bound.